# Shipping stdout and stderr to Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

We have a bunch of services, deployed on Mesos via docker containers, that log to stdout and stderr. We are now introducing ELK and so need to ship this log data to Logstash.

One solution I am considering is to have a wrapper process that starts the service process, catches stdout and stderr and writes that to a file (which is truncated over time) and have [FileBeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) ship that file to LogStash.  Feels like I might be re-inventing a wheel thought, is there a more direct way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Can't you use redirection (>) to write directly to a file?

Comment: could do..but I also want the log output to continue to be output on stdout and stderr as Mesos catches this.  Also, if I did it this way what would truncate the file? Also, we are using structured logging so the wrapper process can log using our structure in the event that the child process dies before restarting it.

Comment: Perhaps with logrotate to truncate the file and the tee command to send to file and stderr/out. But I understand why you would want to use a wrapper in that case

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this which is perfect for my use case: https://github.com/myles-mcdonnell/procwrap